# Python Requests - Sending POST form data multi-part

Tags: python-2.7, http, python-requests

I've looked through the posts here, and I haven't found a solution yet.

I'm trying to send a POST request to send a file to a server.
Part of the form data accepts the binary file, and there are other mandatory fields to add to the form.

The last solution I've tried was this:

```
    my_data = {
        "repo_upload_file": ("filename.pdf", open("filename.pdf", rb), "application/pdf"),
        "sesskey": (None, sess_key),
        "repo_id": (None, repo_id),
        "author": (None, author),
        "savepath": (None, save_path),
        "title": (None, title),
        "itemid": (None, itemid),
        "ctx_id": (None, ctx_id)

    }
    response = session.post("http://mywebsite/repo.php?action=upload", files=my_data)
    print response.content # expecting a json object that stores the url to the uploaded file
```

When I try via my browser (this server has a ui), it works fine. Using fiddler, I've seen that the fields get sent as WebForms :

[image]

However, when using my code, it appears on fiddler that somehow the server doesn't recognize them as WebForms, even though it appears that the request was sent correctly

[image]

[image]

This is how the server expects them, but for some reason this doesn't seem to be working

When I got it working fine from the browser, this was the request form datas:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to post other data which is not file, you should follow one of those

```
my_data = {
        "repo_upload_file": ("filename.pdf", open("filename.pdf", "rb"), "application/pdf")
        }

data = {
        "sesskey": sess_key,
        "repo_id": repo_id,
        "author": author,
        "savepath": save_path,
        "title": title,
        "itemid": itemid,
        "ctx_id": ctx_id
        }
```

Type 1, post data normally

```
response = session.post(url, data = data , files=my_data)
```

Type 2, post as json

```
response =  session.post(url, json = data , files=my_data)
```